# Undefined symbol for an ObjC framework while linking with .mm source

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I have a framework from 3rd party that has implemented this function in their.m file and declrared in their framework header:

void foo();

When i use this in my .mm, i get undefined symbol error for foo().

I am aware that enclosing above declaration in the 3rd party header in extern “C” resolves the linker error.

However, the question is why doesn’t enclosing #include of the framework header in my .mm or associated header resolve it? 
Also, what is the reason the symbol for foo() isn’t found by .mm?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile with .m, `foo` is will be treated as a C symbol. Whereas using a .mm file extension tells Xcode to treat the file as an Objective-C++ file. If you go to the File Inspector, you should see something like this.

[image]

In this case the `foo` undergoes name mangling which is necessary in C++ since the same identifier (`foo` in this case) can be used multiple ways (eg. function overloading).

Since you are including the header in the .mm, it is treated as Objective-C++. You need the `extern "C"` to prevent `foo` from being mangled, which will then enable the linker to use the right symbol name which is in the framework.

Comment: Sorry but could you please describe exactly what change needs to be done when you write "You need the extern "C" to prevent foo from being mangled, which will then enable the linker to use the right symbol name which is in the framework."?